# Find Nearest square number of a given number

Tags: javascript, math

The task is to find the nearest square number, nearest_sq(n), of a positive integer n (taken from codewars). I've tried the below but just get an infinite loop.

```
while(Math.sqrt(n)%1!==0){
    n-- || n++
}
return n;
```

Can someone point out where I am wrong in my logic with this code?

Comment: Nearest in both directions or just greater?

Comment: @bugs...sorry, I should have clarified. Yes, in both directions

Comment: For what value of `n` do you get infinite loop?

Comment: I don't know actually. I am assuming it's an infinite loop because the function always times out(on codewars) returning an error message "function timed out" for whatever n is given

Answer (score 16):

This should be pretty close:

```js
const nearest_sq = n => Math.pow(Math.round(Math.sqrt(n)), 2);

console.log(nearest_sq(117)); // 121
console.log(nearest_sq(900)); // 900
console.log(nearest_sq(15)); // 16
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but can you explain the logic behind this? I was(obviously) way  with my solution and are not understanding the logical flow of what you produced..thanks

Comment: Well, you take the square root of the integer, round it to the nearest number, and then square that. That should give you the closest square number.

Comment: Although nothing different than @RobbyCornelissen's magic the following is other way of doing it.. n => Math.pow(Math.round(Math.pow(n,.5)),2)

Comment: @Robby sorry, I can see that's what you are doing I guess what I getting at is a math formula or something you just derived? I asked because I searched from math formulas before I got to stack overflow and found nothing that looks what you did. Maybe my search wasn't concise or something? I ask this because I would prefer to take the appropriate steps to find the solution on my own rather than someone just give it to me...thanks

Comment: You dont need to call the math functions  `n ** 0.5` is the same as `Math.sqrt(n)` The answer can be found quicker using `(((n ** 0.5) + 0.5) | 0) ** 2;`

Comment: @Blindman67 This [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/math-functions-vs-arithmetic/1) indicates that your version is about 60 percent slower. Plus, it's less readable.

Comment: Yes and a beautiful example of why not to trust jsPref You should try your own benchmark as they will show a completely different result. Both FF and Chrome run the function at the same rate. You will find that ** 0.5 and ** 2 call the same internal function. As for readable, you have got to be kidding?  why not remove all operators `Math.add(a,b)` , is that more readable than `a + b`.

Comment: This https://jsperf.com/power-operators/1 test shows a more accurate result

Comment: @Blindman67 There's no need for hyperbole. Of course I find `a + b` to be more readable than `Math.add(a, b)`, and I'm willing to concede that your version is as fast or maybe even faster than mine. But if you consider adding 0.5 and then performing a bitwise OR operation to be more readable than calling `Math.round()`, then I have to disagree. In fact, the bitwise OR operation won't even pass JSLint.

Comment: Hyperbole needed when the basics of math are considered too complicated for coders to decipher. Linters protecting coders ignorance and ensuring anyone with a keyboard can call them selves a coder. Coding used to be for smart people, how things have changed. BTW not directed at you, just the general state of the industry.

Comment: I know you said your comment was not directed at me, but in this case I'd rather prefer to be the ignorant coder. The coder that doesn't need to remember that `| 0` truncates instead of floors, that doesn't need to remember that `NaN | 0 == 0` and that `13246873231.2 | 0 == 361971343`.

Answer (score 5):

Python program for nearest square number of given number

```
from math import sqrt
def nearest_square(num):
         num1 = round(sqrt(num))**2
         return sqrt(num1)
print(nearest_square(48))
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe it's not the shortest way, but at least i think the code is easy to understand

```
function nearst_sq(n) {
  var nearstLow = nearst_low(n);
  var nearstHigh = nearst_high(n);

  return n-nearstLow < nearstHigh-n ? nearstLow : nearstHigh;
}

function nearst_high(n) {
  if (Math.sqrt(n)%1 === 0) {
    return n;
  }

  return nearst_high(++n);
}

function nearst_low(n) {
  if (Math.sqrt(n)%1 === 0) {
    return n;
  }

  return nearst_low(--n);
}
```

Comment: nice and it makes perfect sense to me!

Comment: @OluwaseyiSarumi If you find this answer to be helpful, please mark it as an answer for further searches.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function nearestSq(n){
    let i,j;
    for(i=j=n;Math.sqrt(i)%1!=0&&Math.sqrt(j)%1!=0;i++,j--);
      return Math.sqrt(i)%1==0?i:j
    }
    console.log(nearestSq(21));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple Python3 implementation

```
from math import sqrt
nearestSqr = lambda x: round(sqrt(x)) ** 2
print(nearestSqr(99))
```

Comment: This question is asked in javascript, so it is not recommended to answer this in other languages since it will not fully answer OP's question

Comment: I found this question searching for the same solution in Python. I used the answers here to make a Python solution, figured I would share it as others may search this problem looking for a python solution to the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
function nearestSq(n) {
  let sqrtOfN = Math.trunc(Math.sqrt(n));
  let result = Math.abs((sqrtOfN*sqrtOfN)-n)>Math.abs((sqrtOfN+1)*(sqrtOfN+1)-n) ? (sqrtOfN+1):sqrtOfN;
  
  if(sqrtOfN*sqrtOfN === n) {
    result = n;
  }
  else {
    result = result*result;
  }  
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

def nearest_sq(n):
    inc = find_square(n, '+')
    dec = find_square(n, '-')
    return inc if inc -n < n - dec else dec 
        
def find_square(n, operator):
    squared_result = math.sqrt(n)
    if (squared_result).is_integer():
        return n
    else:
        next_number = n + 1 if operator == '+' else n - 1 
        return find_square(next_number, operator)
```

Comment: However, I fail with large numbers but my math isn't good enough to know why